# The 'angular way' of adding stored state to an application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

We're developing a single page app e-learning using Angularjs and we've got to the point of needing to track if certain components are 'completable' AND if they are completed.

Unfortunately I'm almost certain my understanding of Angularjs concepts is flawed, so before blundering ahead with some shoe-horned solution, I would like to know what would be the 'angular way' of achieving this.

I have added a custom attribute directive 'eng-completable' to the html template of a component (a popup that displays on a button-click). I could also add a (potentially spurious) ng-model="completed" variable declaration... (the first line below is the relevant one - the others are all working fine)

```
<div eng-completable ng-model="completed" class="hidden popup {{component.popup.type}}" id="{{component.popup.name}}" data-replaces="{{component.popup.replaces}}">
    <div ng-if="component.popup.type=='overlay'">
        <div class="float-right button close-button">X</div>
    </div>
    <p class="heading">{{component.popup.heading}}</p>
    <div class="popup-content">
        <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-start="(innerIndex, component) in component.popup.popup_components"></div>
            <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-start="(type, object) in component"></div>
                <div ng-attr-id="{{'p' + pageId + '-s' + skey + '-c' + ckey + '-component-' + index + '-innerComponent-' + innerIndex}}" ng-switch="type">
                    <div ng-switch-when="image" eng-image></div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="paragraph" eng-paragraph></div>
                </div>
            <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-end></div>
        <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-end></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added the corresponding directive to our app.js file:

```
app.directive('engCompletable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.completed = false;
            console.log("completable attribute encountered and triggered: scope.completed = "+scope.completed);
        }
    }
});
```

But then what? How do I access the completed variable in a 'global' sense? The fact that the next step doesn't seem obvious suggests to me I've already gone awry.

What's the best way to store and track multiple completion variables (in multiple scopes?) in an angular app?

**EDIT**

I think I may need to include more specifics to really reveal my problem:
Assuming I'm able to add a 'completable' property to the scope of each eng-completable directive, when a user clicks a button component which triggers a corresponding popup component (through an id reference to just the DOM element), how do I refer to the angular scope of the popup component to alter the 'completable' property?

I understand that even the framing of the question could be flawed but, if it is, I'd like to know what is the 'right' way to do this, in angular.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you only wanting to know if one thing completed or multiple?

Also how many things are you wanting to trigger?

Comment: There will be any number of completables per app. We've only just added the first interactive component (a popup and corresponding button) but there will be many more types of completable components and they may each appear many times in an app.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing to events is a great way to share data between controllers. Here is an example of sharing to another controller that a comment is finished loading, and 'controller1' will keep track of all comments that were loaded.

Example controller that is waiting to see who is loaded:

```
angular.module('app').controller('controller1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function controller1($scope, $rootScope) {

    var unsubscribe = $rootScope.$on('comment:loaded', commentLoaded);    

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function removeBindings() {
        unsubscribe();
    });

    var commentIdsLoaded = {};
    function commentLoaded(event, comment) {
        commentIdsLoaded[comment.id] = true;
    }

});
```

Controller that is notifying comment loaded

```
angular.module('app').controller('controller2', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function controller2($scope, $rootScope) {

    function commentFinishedLoading(comment) {
        $rootScope.$emit('comment:loaded', comment);
    }

});
```

This solution allows you to manage comments without storing them in $rootScope and only storing data in the model that needs it. It will also prevent memory leaks from happening of storing data about these if you change pages.

Answer (score 0):

Events are probably the most light-weight way for sharing this kind of state between components and is often the way I would *start* handling this kind of problem.

With more inter-component interaction, events can become cumbersome and error prone.  When there are lots of emitters and/or listeners, you need to make sure the right components are handling the right messages.  You are also essentially *duplicating state* in each of the related components, which makes it easy to have out-of-synch issues.

The main alternative is using **a shared service to manage shared state**, which allows there to be no state duplication. Services are singletons, so you might not think they'd work well for managing multiple unique states, but they can hold maps (or arrays) of states just fine, and be watched for changes.

A shared service approach could look something like:

```
// Shared service
angular.module('app').service('completables', function(){
  // A map of, perhaps { exerciseId : isCompleted } 
  var _states = {};
  // You could put getters and setters on here to be more explicit
  return { 'states': _states }
});

// Some high-level controller
angular.module('app').controller('highLevel', ['completables', function(completables){
  $scope.completables = completables;
  $scope.$watch('completeables.states', function(oldStates, newStates){
    // Do something whenever ANY states change
  });  
});

// Low-level directives
app.directive('engCompletable', ['completables', function(completables){ 
  return {
    scope: { exercise: '=' },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      // Set initial (shared) state
      completeables.state[scope.exercise.id] = false;

      // Triggered by user interaction
      scope.completeExercise = function(){
        completeables.state[scope.exercise.id] = true;   
      };

      // You could also watch for external changes to just this exercise
      scope.completables = completeables;
      scope.$watch('completables.' + [scope.exercise.id], function(oldState, newState){
        // Do something when changed externally
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Shared services incur more watchers, so keep that in mind.  But it keeps the state in one place – great for maintaining synch – and it feels a little more robust.